# Serialize dictionary into json

Tags: c#, json

I have dictionary that is defined as:

```
 Dictionary<string, object> d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

I fill it with various keys and values and send it to a web client as Json using the Newton.Json library:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
```

The rest service is defined the following way:

```
[Description("Test method")]
[WebGet( ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
public string Test()
```

But I am getting a problematic json in client:

> \"AdditionalPortfolioCurrencyID\":\"GBP\",\"BaseCurrency\":\"USD\",\"TermCurrency\":\"JPY\",\"PortfolioName\":\"\",\"Book\":\"\",\"Butterfly\":0.0,\"BuySell\":\"Buy\",\"DealId\":\"1\"}

When receiving such json in client extjs store does not present a data

I would like to receive following json

```
{ "AdditionalPortfolioCurrencyID": "GBP", "BaseCurrency": "USD", "TermCurrency": "JPY", "PortfolioName": "", "Book": "", "Butterfly": 0, "BuySell": "Buy", "DealId": "1" }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your output seems like valid JSON - what does your expected output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"problematic" meaning the initial lack of initial '{', or the '\' delimiter?
Where did you get the output from? Is that the expected full body except for the lack of '{', or are you getting more truncation?

Other than that, it's valid JSON...

{
    "AdditionalPortfolioCurrencyID": "GBP",
    "BaseCurrency": "USD",
    "TermCurrency": "JPY",
    "PortfolioName": "",
    "Book": "",
    "Butterfly": 0,
    "BuySell": "Buy",
    "DealId": "1"
}